# Linq statement not reproducing data from sql select in Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to convert the following query from SQL to linq but it's not producing the same result set in .net as it is in SQL Server Management Studio

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP 6 
    [ID], [customerInfo], [IVACODE], [Contribution],
    [DUE_DATE], [isActive], [isDeleted]
FROM 
    [portal].[dbo].[tblPortalContributionSchedule]
WHERE
    customerInfo = '01F6B68B-6FC2-4F9D-B586-6934B8D6C979'
    AND DUE_DATE <= '2016/09/26' 
    AND DUE_DATE <> '2016/09/26'
ORDER BY 
    DUE_DATE DESC
```

In my linq I have so far the following comparison:

```
public List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> getUserContributions(Guid _customerInfoId,DateTime _date)
{
      List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _contributions = 
             portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules
                 .Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerInfoId 
                    && a.isDeleted == false 
                    && a.DUE_DATE <= _date 
                    && a.DUE_DATE !=_date )
                 .Take(6)
                 .OrderByDescending(o=> o.DUE_DATE)
                 .ToList();

        return _contributions;
}
```

My return call is simply then

```
List<tblPortalContributionSchedule> _payments = _dal.getUserContributions(_customerId, Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/26"));
```

This is a screen grab of me data but its not producing the desired results

https://snag.gy/3uKCPh.jpg

I was wondering if someone could help me in converting this properly to linq.

This is the data result I should be getting

https://snag.gy/OQrql8.jpg

Basically I want to get the last 6 payments; there could be 30 payments spread over 7 years but I'm only interested in customer's last 6 payments based on the current month.

Comment: FYI, the two image links you've posted are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Let's deconstruct:

```
portalEntities.tblPortalContributionSchedules
              .Where(a => a.customerInfo == _customerInfoId)
        1 ->  .Where(a => !a.isDeleted)
              .Where(a => a.DUE_DATE <= _date)
        2 ->  .Where(a => a.DUE_DATE != _date)
              .OrderByDescending(a => a.DUE_DATE)
        3 ->  .Take(6)
              .ToList();
```

1. More readable than `== false`
2. Conflicts with statement above it. Just use `<` if you want to exclude it.
3. Place *after* `OrderByDescending`.